# Event when user clicks on a link with hash directing to an anchor inside the page

Tags: javascript, html

How to catch the moment when user clicks a link that has a hash directing inside the same page which is already open (and no navigation between pages happens)? There is `hashchange` event, but it wouldn't fire if the hash is already set and there is no change to it. Browser will scroll the page to the anchor regardless if hash has changed or not.

```
http://example.org/#my-hash
```

Use case where I need it: page has a small "Contents" block at the beginning and user might click an item there, then navigate back to top and click the same item again. I want to highlight the section where user navigates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just get the element using querySelector, then fire your onclick event

```js
window.onload = function() {
var tlink = document.querySelector('a[href="#tlink"]');

tlink.addEventListener('click', function(){
console.log(tlink.getAttribute('href'));
});
}
```

```css
#clink {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:100%;
height:20rem;
background:gray;
}

#tlink {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:100%;
height:20rem;
background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#tlink">GoTo T-Link</a>
<div id="clink"></div>
<div id="tlink">HERE IS T-LINK</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the hash property of the link clicked to the hash property of `location` object

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const isSameHash = el.hash === location.hash;    
    console.log(isSameHash ? 'Already selected' : 'New Hash')
  });
})
```

```html
<a href="#foo">Foo</a><br/><a href="#bar">Bar</a>
```